# Best Introductory Probability Theory Book [Non-Measure Theoretic]

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request

I am currently a junior undergraduate student taking an Introductory Course on Probability Theory. I have been struggling with the subject for the last few weeks because mathematics can be challenging and I haven't built up enough intuition to train my mind to think probabilistically enough.

That being said, I'm between a few choices for a book for supplementary study. I've found the PDFs by Hoel, Port and Stone as well as Hossein-Pishro Nik's online text and Feller Volume 1. I was wondering, which of these books present the material in the most intuitive manner?

I often have a difficult time with Combinatorial Analysis as well, so I'm looking for a book that presents the material intuitively and yet rigorously enough so that I can truly gain a better understanding and grasp of the subject. I am open to any and all recommendations.

Comment: Introduction to Financial Mathematics by Steven Roman has several chapters purely on probability, and I've found them to be the most intuitive and light, yet formal introduction to this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two personal favorites for introductory probability are *A First Course in Probability* by Ross (there are several editions) and *Understanding Probability* by Tijms.  Neither one uses measure theory.  Ross's book is distinguished by its wealth of fully-worked out, interesting examples.  Tijms's book strikes me as slightly more modern, with an emphasis on simulation and an unusual structure; the book is in two parts, with the first part an intuitive approach with lots of examples of applications, and the second part more formal.

I like Feller's book, but I don't think it is a good choice for a first introduction.  Compared to Ross and Tjims, Feller Volume I is more advanced and doesn't have much discussion of continuous distributions.  I can't comment on your other two books because I haven't read them.